# Switch Selection in Buck-Boost Controller Designs

Tags: mosfet, switches, switching-regulator, buck-boost

I have reviewed several buck-boost controller designs, including the [LT8390](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/lt8390.pdf) nd I am puzzled by the selection of different switches for the buck and boost sections. For instance, on page 27, the circuit recommends the following switches:

[image: Buck-boost switch]

Switch M1:[BSZ100N06LS3](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/196/Infineon_BSZ100N06LS3_G_DataSheet_v02_04_EN-3361137.pdf)

Switch M4:[BSZ033NE2LS5](https://www.digikey.be/htmldatasheets/production/1867250/0/0/1/bsz033ne2ls5.html)

[image: BSZ100N06LS3]

[image: BSZ033NE2LS5]

In my analysis, I am unable to comprehend why the MOSFET switch M1 couldn't be used in place of M4. I have observed this pattern in various designs, where these two switches are consistently different. I am seeking clarification on the reasons behind this discrepancy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've mixed up M2 and M4, but I get the gist. The input switches are subjected to up to the maximum input voltage (~56V). The output switches only have to block ~12V.

It's not optimal to use a much higher voltage rated MOSFET than required- you can get a lower Rds(on) by sourcing a lower voltage MOSFET with a similar die size. As you can see, the Rds(on) is much smaller (1/3) for the lower voltage device.

Using the higher voltage devices for both would lead to higher conduction losses. Using the lower voltage devices for both would exceed the device ratings for input voltages at the high end of the range.

If you had a 4-switch buck-boost converter that was intended to operate with input voltage and output voltage approximately the same it would make more sense for all the MOSFETs to be the same. Anyway, you can decide whether the increased efficiency is worth another BOM item.

Comment: Thank you. Just one question: For the block voltage, I was considering that both would see 56V - 12V = 44V. Why is my calculation incorrect? If it is purely buck, M1 sees 44V, and if it is purely boost, M1 will be shorted, and M4 still sees 44V, right?

Comment: M4 acts like a (more ideal) diode. As does M2. Look at the direction of the body diode. Even if you didn't operate the gate the source would not go above 12.6V.

Comment: Understood. Thank you